# missing required keys: [:id] rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I try to run my code, I got the problem above.
Here's my `tasks/_task.html.erb`

```
<% @list.tasks.each do |task| %>
    <p>
        <%= task.name %><%= task.id %>
        <%= link_to "Destroy", to_do_list_task_path(@list, task.id), method: :delete %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

my tasks controller :

```
def destroy
    @list = ToDoList.find(params[:to_do_list_id])
    @task = @list.tasks.find(params[:id])
    if @task.destroy
        redirect_to(:back)
    else
        redirect_to(:back)
    end
end
```

and my routes :

```
resources :to_do_lists do
    resources :tasks
end
```

full error :

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>nil, :to_do_list_id=>"157"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Any idea ?

EDIT to_do_list's controller :

```
def show
    @list = @user.to_do_lists.find(params[:id])
    @task = @list.tasks.new
    @build = @list.tasks.build
end
```

EDIT 2 full error :

```
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c] Started GET "/to_do_lists/158" for ::1 at 2016-05-07 09:14:37 +0200
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c] Started GET "/to_do_lists/158" for ::1 at 2016-05-07 09:14:37 +0200
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c] Processing by     ToDoListsController#show as HTML
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c] Processing by ToDoListsController#show as HTML
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Parameters: {"id"=>"158"}
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Parameters: {"id"=>"158"}
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   ToDoList Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "to_do_lists".* FROM "to_do_lists" WHERE "to_do_lists"."user_id" = $1 AND "to_do_lists"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 24], ["id", 158]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   ToDoList Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "to_do_lists".* FROM "to_do_lists" WHERE "to_do_lists"."user_id" = $1 AND "to_do_lists"."id" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 24], ["id", 158]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]    (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."to_do_list_id" = $1  [["to_do_list_id", 158]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]    (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."to_do_list_id" = $1  [["to_do_list_id", 158]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."to_do_list_id" = $1   [["to_do_list_id", 158]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."to_do_list_id" = $1  [["to_do_list_id", 158]]
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Rendered tasks/_task.html.erb (5.3ms)
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Rendered tasks/_task.html.erb (5.3ms)
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Rendered to_do_lists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (7.6ms)
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]   Rendered to_do_lists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (7.6ms)
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
[localhost] [::1] [6d1ad8d6-bfdf-4c]
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tasks", :id=>nil, :to_do_list_id=>"158"} missing required keys: [:id]):
2:  <% @list.tasks.each do |task| %>
3:      <p>
4:          <%= task.name %><%= task.id %>
5:          <%= link_to "Supprimer", to_do_list_task_path(@list, task), method: :delete %>
6:      </p>
7:  <% end %>
8: </div>
  app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:5:in `block in    _app_views_tasks__task_html_erb___979180469130099435_70290175534220'
  app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_tasks__task_html_erb___979180469130099435_70290175534220'
  app/views/to_do_lists/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_to_do_lists_show_html_erb__2820495566946140584_70290199271140'
```

Comment: What does the controller action that is rendering this view look like?

Comment: I just added the controller action

Comment: @TimothéGauguet, provide full error from server console please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are doing this:

```
@build = @list.tasks.build
```

This adds an unsaved task object to the `list.tasks` collection. Since it is unsaved, it's id is nil and can't be linked to.

Alternatively, skip the "delete" link if the task is not saved (`persisted?` is false).

Comment: I think tasks objects are saved because <%= task.id %> works on the view

Comment: task.id works fine - it just returns nil for the one unsaved task

Comment: Ok, thanks ! How could I solve the problem ? I tried to remove @build and placed his logic in the view but the problem's still here

Comment: You need to stop calling list.tasks.build. Use Task.new if you need an unsaved task for something, or don't render the delete link for unsaved tasks.